# How can I add documents to a collection in MongoDB, without adding duplicate documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I add documents to a collection using insert_many() then when I go to add more documents, for example the same documents as before but with an additionally document (as data is generated daily), I get duplicate entries in my data base. How can I simply add the new document(s) and not have duplicates? I have tried using update_many({},{},{upsert:true}) but nothing appears to be working?

I have tried using update_many({},{},{upsert:true}) but nothing appears to be working?

This is what it looks like in the db, 1st and 2nd Jan 2019 are uploaded then, report is generated on the 3rd and 1st, 2nd and 3rd get added but I only want the 3rd Jan as 1st and 2nd are duplicates

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4178fe4c934b011e86b193"), 
       "date" : ISODate("2019-01-01"), 
        "sessions" : "330", 
        "bounceRate" : "81.22"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4178fe4c934b011e86b194"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-02"), 
    "sessions" : "333", 
    "bounceRate" : "80.21"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4178fe4c934b011e86b195"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-01"), 
    "sessions" : "330", 
    "bounceRate" : "81.22"}

{"_id" : ObjectId("5d4178fe4c934b011e86b196"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-02"), 
    "sessions" : "333", 
    "bounceRate" : "80.21"}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4178fe4c934b011e86b197"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2019-01-03"), 
    "sessions" : "340", 
    "bounceRate" : "79.45"}
```

Comment: You could do it on the client-side. Before doing the import, fetch the latest document date. Then simply don't insert documents that are lower than it.

Comment: You could also create a unique index on a combination of fields that should be unique

Comment: How would the index method work exactly? For example: db.collection.createIndex( { ISODate:1, sessions: 1, bounceRate: 1 }, {unique:true} ). Would I insert_many() for the first pull and then create an index, so that subsequent pulls would not be duplicated?